I have used iscroll as a custome scroll and try to fix hader on top can't able to do that and also position is not working in iscroll?
I have used iscroll as a custom scroll and try to fix hader on top can't able to do that and also position is not working in iscroll. How to use position in iscroll?

https://codepen.io/gopal-jadav/pen/VwJWqPp
